# Is there a way to only store the 50 most recent values in a CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I am reading values from a temperature sensor with python and writing them to a CSV file.

Would there be a way to only store the 60 most recent values as I am currently just overwriting the file every 60 values?

Comment: you should add more detail to this question.  Please provide the code you have already, what works and what doesn't and we'll try our best to help!

Comment: Yes, One way would be by reading the file and storing the data in a fixed-size [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `iloc` to split the dataframe according to the index count. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

temp = pd.read_csv(r'...') #read csv from location
temp60 = temp.iloc[:60,:] #counting from zero, keeps the most recent 60 values
temp60.to_csv (r'...') #export dataframe as csv to location
```